# Embed section elements in divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, embed

I have three section elements that look like this:

```
<section class="rbs-section" id="rbi_S_12466479" name="world1">
<p>Hello World1</p>
</section>

<section class="rbs-section" id="rbi_S_12466477" name="world2">
<p>Hello World2</p>
</section>

<section class="rbs-section" id="rbi_S_12466478" name="world3">
<p>Hello World3</p>
</section>
```

and I am trying to get them in divs like this:

```
<div class="world">
    <section class="rbs-section" id="rbi_S_12466479" name="world1">
    <p>Hello World1</p>
    </section>
</div>
<div class="world">
    <section class="rbs-section" id="rbi_S_12466477" name="world2">
    <p>Hello World2</p>
    </section>
</div>
<div class="world">
    <section class="rbs-section" id="rbi_S_12466478" name="world3">
    <p>Hello World3</p>
    </section>
</div>
```

How can I create divs and then move these sections to those divs? What is the easiest way to achieve this? Kindly let me know.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`.wrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/) at this context to ease up your work,

```
$(".rbs-section").wrap("<div class='world' />")
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mv2fys68/1/)

Comment: Doesn't perform it on the individual sections instead does it on the all the sections as a whole.

Comment: @TheNewbie Sorry was in a confusion. See the updated code now.

Comment: Thanks that works now. I'm ready to accept that as an answer however I have an issue and I'm not sure if you could help. This is what I'm trying to do and the above question is kind of relevant to this: http://dojo.telerik.com/oZari
So instead of those weather div's, I had sections and I have just updated the code to make them appear as divs now. However the kendo tabstrip code still doesn't work. I'll update a comment here with the JsFiddle.

Comment: @TheNewbie Actually if I do answering your sub questions, that will make this post polluted. Instead of that, you could create that as a new question, so that the new question will get attention of more experts rather than me and that will help the future visitors also. :)

Comment: that's true.. Thanks.